# NFC tag is not discovered for ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED action even if it contains Ndef data

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, mifare, ndef

I am trying to read 2 different NFC tags with a Samsung S5. Both tags contain an NDEF message, the first tag contains a MIME type record as its first record and the second tag contains an alternative carrier record (TNF = TNF_WELL_KNOWN, Type = RTD_ALTERNATIVE_CARRIER) as its first record.

When I read the tags through the foreground dispatch using `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` intent. For the first tag, the tech-list lists `NfcA`, `MifareClassic`, and `Ndef`. For the second tag, it lists `NfcA` and `Ndef`.

When I try to read the tag using `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent using the datatype "*/*" , the first tag is discovered fine, but the second tag is not discovered at all.

Comment: What data is stored on the two tags?

Comment: Just simple testing data written in Ndef format.

Comment: Ok, to clarify my question: What's the data type of the first NDEF record in the NDEF messages on those tags?

Comment: in 1st tag TNFType = TNF_MIME_MEDIA and in 2nd tag TNFType = TNF_WELL_KNOWN, RTDType = RTD_ALTERNATIVE_CARRIER

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is how the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter works. With the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` you can either watch for a certain datatype (i.e. a MIME type) or for a certain URI. In all cases, the matching will be applied for the *first* record in the NDEF message of a discovered tag.

With **datatype matching**, you can detect

- a MIME type record that contains the given MIME media type or
- a Text RTD record (TNF_WELL_KNOWN + RTD_TEXT) with maps to the MIME type "text/plain".

With **URI matching**, you can detect

- a URI RTD record (TNF_WELL_KNOWN + RTD_URI),
- a URI RTD record encapsulated inside a Smart Poster RTD record,
- a record with a URI based type (TNF_ABSOLUTE_URI), or
- an NFC Forum External Type record (TNF_EXTERNAL).

Both matching types are mutually exclusive, so you can either match for a datatype or for a URI in one intent filter.

In the case of your second tag, the type of the first record (TNF_WELL_KNOWN + RTD_ALTERNATIVE_CARRIER) is not supported by the NDEF intent dispatch system. Hence, you cannot use the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter in combination with that tag.

### Examples

Matching for a datatype:

- in the manifest:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <data android:mimeType="some/mimetype" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- in code:

  ```
  IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
  ndef.addDataType("some/mimetype");
  ```

Matching for a URL:

- in the manifest:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="somehost.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/somepath" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- in code:

  ```
  IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
  ndef.addDataScheme("http");
  ndef.addDataAuthority("somehost.example.com", null);
  ndef.addDataPath("/somepath", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX);
  ```

Matching for an NFC Forum External Type:

- in the manifest:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
            android:host="ext"
            android:pathPrefix="/com.example:sometype" />
  </intent-filter>
  ```
- in code:

  ```
  IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
  ndef.addDataScheme("vnd.android.nfc");
  ndef.addDataAuthority("ext", null);
  ndef.addDataPath("/com.example:sometype", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX);
  ```